# Packard Bell EasyNote TE69KB is crashing because of battery overcharge?

Tags: laptop, windows-8.1, graphics-card, cpu, battery

I have a Packard Bell EasyNote TE69KB Notebook with an AMD-E1 2500 APU, AMD Radeon HD8240 graphics and 2 GB Ram. On the Notebook is Windows 8.1 installed with all updates and all drivers are updated.

My problem is that the Notebook is crashing after some time with lines in rainbow color or it reboots immediately.

The lines disappear after reboot.

I have seen that it happens only if the battery is near 100% charged and the notebook is charging. Without the charging(only with battery) the problem does not exist.

Is it possible that "overcharge" causes the lines and reboots? What can I do to avoid it?

Comment: Is your laptop getting overheat when this happens? Probably may not be a battery charge issue, but something with overheat due to internal cooler failure.

Comment: @vembutech thanks for the quick response. The temperature(CPU, GPU..) is at 46-47° C. The notebook often crashes 5-10 min after booting(cold start), but only if it is charging and the battery is near 100%. Without charging it is not crashing.

Comment: You can't overcharge the battery, so that isn't it.  What happens if you remove the battery and run on just the charger?

Comment: I have checked it and it is crashing. Could it be a sensor that makes problems?

Comment: I had this happen with my Sony Vaio.  I determined that the charger mechanism detected what it believed was an overcharge situation and shut the system down to "protect" the battery.  The near-term solution was to do a couple discharge cycles on the battery (run on battery only until nearly discharged).  This resets the charger's "meter" of how much the battery is charged.  The long-term solution was to find and enable the "battery care" function which prevents the battery from being charged over 80%.

Comment: Just guess. It look related to noise filtration. When battery charging, it work as additional resistance in RC filter and noise not pass. When battery fully charged it disconnected by charge controller, resistance of load is lowered and noises start to pass.
It can be related to dried (broken) capacitors in PSU or Notebook.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I have solved the problem. It was a BIOS/UEFI problem. My Windows 8.1 was installed with BIOS LEGACY mode. After I have changed it to UEFI the problems disappear.